# Correct way to return the local day and time in python

Tags: python, sql

I'm new to python and I am trying to return the local day and time.
As usual for programming there are different ways of doing this.
One method is to get the time zone:

```
now_date = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Bucharest'))
```

This one works fine.

Another method that I like it's to get the database date.
I find this a little tricky. I tried like this:

```
np_server_date = pd.read_sql(sql='SELECT NOW() as data', con=engine)
date_object = np_server_date.ix[0][data]
now_date = data_object
```

I think I am missing something because it returns an error

```
"global name "data" it's not defined"
```

What am I missing, because they are declared in the same function. And it's there a difference between the two ways of getting the data?
Here it's my full code:

```
def getlocaldata():
    ref_time = dt.time(7,00).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    aux_time = dt.time(7,0).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    np_server_date = pd.read_sql(sql='SELECT NOW() as data', con=engine)
    date_object = np_server_date.ix[0][data]
    now_date = data_object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put quotes around `data`.

`np_server_date.ix[0]['data']` will solve the error.

One more thing, the next line after this, will probably raise an error, because `data_object` is not defined. Rewrite to `date_object`.

Comment: :) You're perfectly right. Before I can accept your answer can you please tell me if it's a difference between the two methods ?

Comment: and it doesnt make sense that you're first storing the value in `date_object` and then transferring to `new_date`. Directly store in `new_date`.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of difference. In the first method, you are choosing the timezone as per your wish, in the second one, you get the date in whatever the database timezone is. Also, the difference of performance, where first one will run faster than the second.